# Rails link_to generating error on page loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code in my view:

```
<% if @user.marine? %>
  <div>
    <%= link_to("Close account".html_safe, deactivate_path(@user), method: :patch, 
        html_options = { role: "button", class: "button-small", data: "Are you certain?" 
        }) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

On loading the page on the development server, this generates the error below, referring to the `<% end %>` line.

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => })
>   );@output_buffer.safe_append= 
>  syntax error, unexpected
>   keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end

Anyone got an idea what in the link-code is causing the error and how I should adjust for it?

I think it has to do with the `data: "Are you certain?"` part. This should pop-up a confirmation message. I also tried `confirm: "Are you certain?"` instead but that made no difference.

**Update:** I can't get the link to work unless I remove the entire `html_options` part. Just removing the `data: "Are you certain?"` part is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a hash key, there should be `:` or `=>` instead of `=`. Try the following, grouping all `html_options` in one hash like this:

```
 <%= link_to 'Close account'.html_safe,
              deactivate_path(@user),
              { method: :patch, role: 'button', class: 'button-small', data: { confirm: 'Are you certain?'} } %>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Simply changing to `html_options:` wasn't sufficient. So needed to apply the example you provided.

Comment: Only the confirmation pop-up isn't working. It just removes the account immediately without asking for confirmation. Would you perhaps know why it is? I also tried `confirm: 'Are you certain?'` but that made no difference.